# Refused to execute script from '...js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled

Tags: c#, .net

Refused to execute script from 'scripts.reportviewer.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled

i have a problem whit report viewer in this menu not enabled options, For example, it does not show the number of pages and the export button does nothing.

the solutions for the same errors have not worked for me